# Duda acerca de "document.form.textview.value" (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

Hoola, muy buenas.

Veréis, estaba curioseando por YouTube vídeos acerca de speedcodes relacionados con Javascript y me he encontrado con un vídeo donde realiza una calculadora con el siguiente código en uno 13 - 15 minutos.

El caso es que no entiendo una cosa que aparece en su código y es el `document.form.textview.value`, no entiendo qué significa eso.

Por deducción y por lógica sé que es el valor del formulario (el valor de donde hago click) pero no me queda muy claro y me gustaría saber de dónde sale ese valor y básicamente, cómo consigo ese valor ya que he buscado por Internet y no he sabido encontrar nada concreto.

```js
function insert(num){
                document.form.textview.value=document.form.textview.value+num;
            }
            
            function equal(){
                var exp=document.form.textview.value;
                if(exp){
                      document.form.textview.value=eval(exp)
                }
            }
            function clean(){
                document.form.textview.value="";
            }
            function back(){
                var exp=document.form.textview.value;
                document.form.textview.value=exp.substring(0,exp.length-1);
            }
```

```css
 *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                
                }
           .button{
                width:50;
                height:50;
                font-size:25;
                margin:2;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .textview{
                width:223;
                margin:5;
                font-size:25;
                padding:5;
            }
            .main{
                position:absolute;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
                backround:
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body bgcolor=,#FF00FF>
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="main">
            <form name = "form">
                <input class="textview" name="textview">
            </form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="C" onclick="clean()"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="<" onclick="back('<')"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="/" onclick="insert('/')"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="x" onclick="insert('*')"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="7" onclick="insert(7)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="8" onclick="insert(8)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="9" onclick="insert(9)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="-" onclick="insert('-')"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="4" onclick="insert(4)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="5" onclick="insert(5)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="6" onclick="insert(6)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="+" onclick="insert('+')"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="1" onclick="insert(1)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="2" onclick="insert(2)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button"type="button"value="3" onclick="insert(3)"></td>
                    <td rowspan=5><input class="button"style="height:106"type="button"value="=" onclick="equal()"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><input class="button"style="width:107"type="button"value="0" onclick="insert(0)"></td>
                     <td><input class="button"type="button"value="." onclick="insert('.')"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Gracias de antemano y un saludo!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La línea `document.form.textview.value` hace referencia al valor (*`value`*) del elemento (*en este caso `<input>`*) con nombre `textview`  del formulario (*`<form>`*) con nombre `form` del documento (*[`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document)*)

Es decir:

```
document
  -> form[name="form"]
       -> input[name="textview"]
            -> value
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Marcos, me resolviste la duda!